# Applying a custom function to an entire formula (without arrayformula())

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help applying a function to an entire column. I am aware that dragging the bottom right handle will copy it however far I drag/highlight. But I would prefer it to be applied to the entire column. I am also aware of the ARRAYFORMULA() function. But it can only be used for basic formulas and functions (at least as far as I am aware). So is there some function (i.e. APPLYALL(range, function)) that will allow me to apply a formula across a column. Or is that up to me to make? Would it be possible to tailor a function to the ARRAYFORMULA function and have it work that way? All help is appreciated.

Here's a snippet of code. The parameters are both strings and it is called by the cells in E2. So for E2 it would look like "toStart(C2,D2)" and for E3 it would look like "toStart(C3,D3)" and so on and so forth.

```
function toStart(model,type) {
  if (model == "E340") {return E340Price(type)}     //Calls same function add OR op
  else if (model == "E342") {return E340Price(type)} //""                         ""
  else if (model == "E350") {return E350Price(type)}
  else if (model == "T644") {return T644Price(type)}
  else if (model == "C532") {return C532Price(type)}
}

function E340Price (type){
  if (type == "Toner") {return 89.00;} //Use global constants for prices?
  else if (type == "Photoconductor") {return 65.00;}
  else if (type == "Toner/Photoconductor") {return 144.00;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a copy paste of the formula which much faster and efficient.
for eg:

```
var lastRow = ThisSheet.getLastRow();
ThisSheet.getRange("E2").setFormula("=toStart(C2,D2)");
ThisSheet.getRange("E2").copyTo(ThisSheet.getRange("E2:E"+lastRow));
```

Then automatically the formulas will scale according to the row numbers. I hope your issue will be resolved then.

EDIT: getLastrow should be getLastRow() and setFormula is actually setFormula() rather than setFormula =

Answer (score 1):

You can enable your function for ranges. The trick is to check if your argument is an array or not, then you simply iterate through all cells.
To simplify, I use a function myFunctionCanRange(x) with only one parameter.
The function that actually calculates the data is myFunction(x).

The code snippets :

```
function myFunctionCanRange(x) {
  if ( Array.isArray(x)) {
    var result = [];
    for( var i=0; i < x.length, i++) {
      var temp = [];
      for ( var j=0; j < x[i].length, j++) {
        temp.push(myFunction(x[i][j]);
      }
      result.push(temp)
     }
     return result;
    }
  else
    return myFunction(x);
}
```

Now you can call it in 2 ways:

> =myFunctionCanRange(C3)

but also:

> =arrayformula(myFunctionCanRange(C3:C))

Comment: `x.length, i++ ` should be `;` inside of comma.  `temp.push(myFunction(x[i][j])` just missing  `)`

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the code, Ling ! You are perfectly right.  Sorry for being so sloppy.